# Optional chaining for interfaces in typescript

Tags: typescript

Is there optional chaining for interfaces in typescript, ex:

```
interface A {
  open?: () => void;
}

function Pro(b?: A) {
  type C = typeof b?.open; // imagine this
}
```

since 'b' is possibly 'undefined'. I should access open in a safe way.

Comment: What is the intended operand of `typeof` here? It would help if you added parentheses for clarification.

Comment: @Dai, typeof open

Comment: Is `Pro` supposed to be generic in the type of `B`?  Or do you really want `Pro` to just be of type `A | undefined` and are looking for a utility type similar to optional chaining?  If so you can sort of do it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXyyQN), but there's no way to completely emulate `?.` at the type level since it has complex behavior.  Anyway if my `Qdot` type meets your needs, let me know and I'll write up an answer explaining. If not, can you [edit] to clarify what's missing?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a conditional type:

```js
interface A {
  open?: () => void;
}

function Pro(b?: A) {
  type C = typeof b extends A ? A['open'] : undefined;
}
```

But this is not strictly different than:

```js
function Pro(b?: A) {
  type C = A['open'];
}
```

So I assume that your real issue is more complex than this.

Comment: This is also just `type C = A['open']`, since `undefined` is already included.